# Passing a Variable out of a Void function to another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsobject

Good Morning ,

I have been trying to make a dynamic message box on a UIAlertView but i havent been managing , im sending data from one class to another using the command :

```
   message = @"Now Starting Download";
   transition.message = self.message;
    NSLog(@"%@",message);
```

Over here message shows `@"Now Starting Download"`
When i go over to the other class (transition class) , i implement using this code :

```
-(id) showmessage:(NSString *)trans
{

    NSLog(@"%@ This is in the transition class",message);

    return trans;
}
```

and message now is empty :@

Any help would be appreciated

-Chris

Comment: Shouldn't the showMessage function return NSString*, not id?  It makes no sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
-(id) showmessage:(NSString *)trans
{

    NSLog(@"%@ This is in the transition class",message);

    return trans;
}
```

makes no sense.  First off, if you're only using the class to NSLog an NSString*, why not just return an NSString*?  Also, you want to NSLog the object passed in the method, because that's all that matters here.  Here's my suggested edits:

```
-(NSString*) showmessage:(NSString *)trans
    {

        NSLog(@"%@ This is in the transition class",trans);

        return trans;
    }
```

If this doesn't work, or prints null, then you are definitely not taking ownership, or suggesting a strong enough retain length, of the string you are passing to this method.

Or, to take a different approach, you imply that you want the class of the object coming through, which would be why you decided to return (id), in which case, you might try

```
NSLog(@"%@ This is in the transition class",NSStringFromClass([trans class]));
```

or even add a sender argument to your method: `-(NSString*) showmessage:(NSString *)trans withSender:(id)sender;`

Comment: Thanks , this helped , i will now sit down and try and get this stuff sorted , i put an NSLog in the method so that i can see if a variable is being sent from one object to another. Will post an update if i manage , thanks again 

-Chris

Comment: No problem.  Just little idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what means "go over", but if `showmensage` is a method of the transition object, you can use the full name:

```
 -(id) showmessage:(NSString *)trans {
      NSLog(@"%@ This is in the transition class",self.message);
      return trans;
   }
```

On the other hand I wonder, why you pass `trans` to `showmensage`, if you don't use it.

Comment: sorry i used such generic terms ,"go over" means when i attempt to pass the data from the first object to the next , i just added a line to the make trans equal to message

trans = message ;
return trans ;

Comment: in the main class i added this line to attempt to see what the hell is going on    transition = [[TransitionClass alloc] showmessage:MessageBoard.text]; ..... MessageBoard.text is the textfield that dynamically shows data